# Why code in static block does not execute?

Tags: java

When I print the `constant` in `main`, the `static` block does not execute, but when I print `stat`, it does execute. Is there any importance to `static final` in Java?

```
package com.test.doubt;

class Doubt {

  public static final int constant = 123;
  public static int stat = 123;

  static {
    System.out.println("Static Block");
  }
}

public class MyProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Doubt.constant);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `static final int` will get compiled directly into your code as its value. That is to say, the JVM sees and is executing:

```
System.out.println(123);
```

and you're not touching your aptly-named `Doubt` class at all (this is an argument for **not** specifying constants in this fashion, btw. If you change that value you have to recompile *every* referencing class)

Answer (score 21):

Your code isn't initializing the `Doubt` class, precisely because `Doubt.constant` *is* a constant. Its value is baked into `MyProgram` at compile-time - you could even delete `Doubt.class` after compilation and your program would still run.

Run

```
javap -c com.test.doubt.MyProgram
```

to have a look at exactly what your code looks like after compilation.

See [section 15.28 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for what constitutes a constant expression. For example, this would still be a constant:

```
public static final String FOO = "Foo";
```

and so would *all* of these:

```
public static final String FOO = "Foo";
public static final String BAR = "Bar";
public static final String FOOBAR = FOO + BAR;
```

... but this wouldn't be

```
public static final String NOT_A_CONSTANT = "Foo".substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: +1 In other words, the `javac` compiler optimised away the need for the `Doubt` class.

Comment: @Thilo: No, it *does* happen for String as well, so long as it's a compile-time constant. See section 15.28 of the JLS for details.

Comment: `package com.test.doubt;
class Doubt{
 public static final int constant = 123;
 public static int stat = 123;

 static {
  System.out.println("Static Block");
 }

}
public class MyProgram {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

//  System.out.println(Doubt.constant);
  System.out.println(Doubt.stat);
  
  
 }

}
` but this code prints the static block,hence i get confused

Comment: I just tried it and AFAIK this happens for any constant known at compile time.

Comment: Also note the side-effect this has when you try to change the constant by by updating the referred class file. Does not work, because the definition is only used at compile-time (of the class that uses it).

Comment: @jenuine You are using a value which is not a constant at compile time, so the class has to be loaded.

Comment: @jenuine: Yes, `stat` is not a constant - it's not final.

Comment: Re: String. Wow, did not know that. Is that special treatment for String? It cannot work that way for any old object, right?

Comment: Done :-) So it is primitives *and* Strings. Apparently not Integer, for example.

Comment: @Thilo: Indeed - which would have made sense to include if autoboxing had been present right from the start, admittedly...

Comment: A lot of things would be nicer if Java had started at 5 ;-)