# Why static initializer block not run in this simple case?

Tags: java, static, load, initialization

```
 class Z
{
    static final int x=10;
    static
    {
        System.out.println("SIB");
    }

}
public class Y
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Z.x);
    }
}
```

Output :10
why static initialization block not load in this case?? when static x call so all the static member of  class z must be load at least once but static initialization block not loading.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863800/why-code-in-static-block-does-not-execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called
>   **static fields** or **class variables**. **They are associated with the class,
>   rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a
>   class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.** Any object
>   can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also
>   be manipulated without creating an instance of the class

So, when you call `Z.x` as below:

```
System.out.println(Z.x);
```

It won't initialize the class, except when you call that `Z.x` it will get that `x` from that fixed memory location.

Static block is runs when JVM loads `class Z`. Which is never get loaded here because it can access that `x` from directly without loading the class.

Answer (score 1):

compile time Z.x value becomes 10, because

```
static final int x=10; is constant
```

so compiler creates code like given below, after inline

```
System.out.println(10); //which is not calling Z class at runtime
```

Comment: +1 This does seem to be a reason. Removing `final` keyword executes the static block. May be kinda compiler optimization.

Comment: @Apurv: This is all explained pretty well in the duplicate linked to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863800/why-code-in-static-block-does-not-execute)

Comment: removing static or final will call static initializer block. Removing static means we have to create object of the class  Z which will be loaded at runtime. Removing final means value can be changed and is not a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when jvm load a class, it put all the class's constant members into the constant area,  when you need them, just call them directly by the class name, that is to say, it needn't to instantiate the class of Z. so the static initialization block is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

It does not run because the class is never loaded.

```
public class Y
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Z z new Z(); //will load class
        System.out.println(Z.x);
    }
}
```

Since the `x` field on `Z` has been declared with `static final` they are created in a fixed memory location.  Accessing this field does not require the class to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If X wouldn't have been final, in that case JVM have to load the class 'Z' and then only static block would be executed. Now JVM need not to load the 'Z' class so static block is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

A constant is called perfect constant if it is declare as static final.
When compiler compiling class y & while compiling sop(Z.x) it replace sop(Z.x) with
sop(10) bcz x is a perfect constant that it means in byte code class Y not use 
class Z so while running class Y class Z is not load thats why SIB of class Z is not
execute.